# Como personalizar uma toolbar no android?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para adicionar mais botões na minha toolbar?

Comment: Lá no XML você adiciona mais itens como buttons. Poste seu layout(view) aqui para implementarmos.

Answer (score 1):

Eu consegui assim veja se é o que você quer.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <Spinner
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:id="@+id/spinnerBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Ele nao quer um spinner, ele precisa de mais botoes um do lado do outro

Comment: O conceito é o mesmo, apenas substitua o Spinner por um image view.

Comment: Nao eh ali que se modifica o conteudo de uma toolbar, vc usa um arquivo XML de menu.

Comment: Ok, mas se ele quiser adicionar um botão a esquerda da toolbar ele nao conseguirá apenas com o XML de menu, de uma olhada no link para ver se fica claro. 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/33277286/5140172

Comment: A sua resposta sairia valorizada se acrescentasse uma pequena explicação.

Comment: Obrigado, @ramaral ainda sou novo aqui e não sei direito como explicar vou tentando melhorar :)

Comment: Seria suficiente referir que Toolbar herda de ViewGroup e que, por isso, é possível acrescentar qualquer tipo de *view* a ele.